# No error in console or logcat but app isn't running properly

Tags: android, runtime-error

The main windows was supposed to be a scrollable grid of images loaded from the web but it will just keep spinning that circle forever without showing anything. I've tested the image links in another app and they are fine. Navigation drawer is loading without problems but the main window just keeps rolling and rolling. The worst part of all is that there's no log. What is the standard procedure for that, i there is one?

Comment: You can add your own logs...

Comment: damn, I was trying to avoid that - I know I should have kept trying to run every once in a while but I guess I'm past that point now - , I've written a lot and I don't have a clue where it broke all of a sudden. Any tip or will I have to go from possible breakpoint to possible breakpoint putting Logs all over the place?

Comment: You've written a lot of code, so you know it better than anyone else. There is no magic...